# loop through specific excel columns using go

Tags: excel, go

In my code below I'm using the [**exclize**](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize) library to read data from an excel sheet.

My problem is that the `.GetRows` method reads the entier sheet when I'm only interested in getting the data from a few columns.

Looking through the [goDoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize#File.GetRows) I couldn't find a method that gives you the data based on column index or name.

Is there a way, in spite of this, to only read the data from a select few columns? Or limit the range of the `.GetRows` method somehow

Here's the code:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
)

type AllData struct {
    Name, Team, SSN string
}

var mapping []AllData

func main() {

    fileName := "Blad1"

    xlsx, err := excelize.OpenFile(fileName + ".xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    rows := xlsx.GetRows(fileName)
    for _, row := range rows[1:] {
        mapping = append(mapping, AllData{ Name: row[0] })
    }

    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "Data": mapping,
    }

    fmt.Println(m["Data"])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are at least a couple more ways

by using rows iterator

```golang
rows, err := xlsx.Rows("Sheet1")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
for rows.Next() {
    row := rows.Columns()
    fmt.Printf("%s\t%s\n", row[1], row[3]) // Print values in columns B and D
}
```

or if you know the exact range

```golang
n := 10001
for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
    b := xlsx.GetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("B%d", i))
    d := xlsx.GetCellValue("Sheet1", fmt.Sprintf("D%d", i))

    fmt.Printf("%s\t%s\n", b, d) // Print values in columns B and D
}
```

*I didn't go through the source of the library so it may or may not make a difference in terms of performance and (or) memory usage.*

Comment: That second option looks promising, I'll have a look at it tomorrow and see if it made a differrence, thank you!

Comment: Second option was a lot faster, saved me ~4 seconds, thanks again!